# RegEx for matching N-digit plus consecutive numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to clean input strings using javascript on node.js. some input strings might contain phone numbers (or random sequence of numbers) which I would like to remove. For example:

Input String: `Terrace 07541207031 RDL 18.02`

after cleaning I would like the string to be: `Terrace RDL 18.02`

I would like to detect numbers (say greater than 4 digits) and remove it.

Comment: Replace `\d{4,}` with empty string.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I am getting a SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token on the regex.

Comment: @user7331538 `"Terrace 07541207031 RDL 18.02".replace(/\d{4,}/,"")` seems to work fine, no SyntaxError on Chrome anyway.  ps, if you want to get rid of the extra space, you could also do `/\s\d{4,}/`

Comment: @Keith I am not experienced with regex and previously I only used '\d{4,}' instead of  '/\d{4,}/' Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/FjZqaF/1) likely matches your desired inputs.

```
(\s)([0-9]{4,})(\s?)
```

If you wish to match any 4 digit plus numbers, you can simply remove the left and right <kbd>space</kbd> check boundaries:

```
([0-9]{4,})
```

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(\s)([0-9]{4,})(\s?)/gm;
const str = `Terrace 07541207031 RDL 18.02
Terrace 07541 RDL 18.02
Terrace 075adf8989 RDL 18.02
Terrace 075adf898 RDL 18.02
075898 RDL 18.02
Terrace RDL 98989https://regex101.com/r/FjZqaF/1/codegen?language=javascript`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### Performance Test

This script returns the runtime of your input string against the expression.

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const regex = /(.*\s)([0-9]{4,})(\s.*)/gm;
 const str = "Terrace 07541207031 RDL 18.02";
 const subst = `$1$3`;

 var match = str.replace(regex, subst);
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

#### RegEx

If this was not your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/FjZqaF/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]